# Use D3.js single line graph to display same date but different temperatures

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this simple d3.js single line graph that is displaying multiple dates across the x-axis:

```
<script>

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
.orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("#air_temp_chart")
.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
});

var tickValues = data.map(function(d) { return d.date; });

xAxis
.tickValues(tickValues)
.tickFormat(d3.time.format('%H:%M'));

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

// Add the valueline path.
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(data));

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

});

data.csv:

```
date,close
1-May-12,58.13
30-Apr-12,53.98
27-Apr-12,67.00
```

**I'd like to change the data so that the date is the same for all, but the times and temperature readings are different values.**

I changed the time.format line to:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y %H").parse;
```

to include the times with the readings, but the graph breaks when I do this.

I'd like to use this data with the same date but different times and temperature readings:

```
1-May-12 06:00,58.13
1-May-12 06:30,53.98
1-May-12 07:00,67.00
```

How do I modify the x-axis code to work with the values above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide specific tick values to be displayed on a d3 chart.

Firstly, correct your date parser:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%e-%b-%y %H:%M").parse;  // %e instead of %d
```

First, you need to get the list of tick values you want to display. After you've loaded the csv and processed it, extract the tick values and assign them to your `xAxis`:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });
    var tickValues = data.map(function(d) { return d.date; });

    xAxis
        .tickValues(tickValues)
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%H:%M'));
```

Do not forget to remove the `ticks` on your current `xAxis` definition.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask you to update my code to reflect your suggestions? I am confused on where to place the tickValues line and do I just replace the old xAxis variable declaration with what you provided? Thanks again!

Comment: @cpcdev I've edited my answer to be more specific. the code goes line by line

Comment: Thank you! I placed the var tickValues line correctly but xAxis is still having problems. I updated my original post to show you the xAxis code I changed. What am I missing here?

Comment: @cpcdev you've commented the `orient('bottom')` as well. Remove only the `ticks` from your current `xAxis` definition. THEN, inside your `d3.csv()` call, after your `data.forEach` code, add the code from my answer exactly as it is. You need to define the `tickValues` after you have loaded the data and the you update your `xAxis` with tickValues

Comment: @cpcdev leave your `xAxis` definition as it was initially (without the tickValues and tickFormat), only remove the `ticks` from it.

Comment: I updated the original code based on your suggestions. Unfortunately there still seems to be something incorrect... by remove "ticks" from the .orient line did you mean remove it altogether or replace it with tickValues? Even when I replace it with .orient("bottom").tickValues(5); something is wrong it seems

Comment: Console errors:

mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create d3.v3.min.js:3:10379
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. index.html
TypeError: n is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108559/discussion-between-iulian-and-cpcdev).

Comment: can I ask how to replicate this graph? Lets say the next graph represents humidity. I tried to copy and paste the code and then change the d3.select identifier to the humidity_chart div. Rather than duplicating the copy, it only displayed one chart and moved it from the temperature chart to the humidity chart section.

Comment: what code exactly did you copy? You can wrap your code in a function that expects an `id` and `dataFile` arguments and creates a chart in the given div with the provided data file. But this is out of scope of this question. I would suggest you create another question in which you could provide more details on what you've done and what does not work.